# Python——Is there any solution for thread priority in threading.Thread？

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm wondering if it is possible to "set" thread priority in python's *threading* lib.

To be clear, I've searched this question and I know that threading lib is not supporting thread priority mechanism due to the internal limitation caused by PIL. BUT I'm just looking for **simulating** this mechanism with some tricks. Is it possible?  Thanks!